# If I delete a voice memo from the Music app, will it also be deleted from the Voice Memo app?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music.app, voice-memo

I want to remove the voice memos from my Music so it doesn't come up when playing songs, but I want to keep the voice memos.

***To clarify, I did not purposely move my voice memos to the Music app.  When I synced my phone to iTunes, all of my voice memos were added to my music library, and when I synced again later on, those voice memos were added to my phone as songs.***

Will deleting voice memos from the Music.app also delete them in the Voice Memos.app?

I use an iPhone 6s running iOS 11.

Comment: How to find your answer: 1) Create a new voice memo that you don't mind being permanently deleted; 2) Sync your phone to iTunes, repeat until you see the memo synced to the Music app; 3) Delete the file in the Music app; 4) Sync with iTunes; 5) Check to see if the file exists in each app

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it on iOS 11 with a new VoiceMemo. Here is what have I done:

I have created a new voice memo, then I have synced the phone to the computer (running latest iTunes). The voice memo showed up in both my music collection in iTunes (even separate playlist) and within the songs on the phone. At least according to iTunes. But then I have tried to search for voice memos in the Music app, but it did not show up. Was this done with some old software?

Anyhow deleting the voice memo on the computer - never mind what it says - will leave it on the phone. But of course, I suggest to back up.

Comment: Screenshots please!

Answer (score 0):

Save those memos to Dropbox. You will need the Dropbox app installed though. Once saved, then you can remove them without worrying about whether or not they are deleted.

Once you delete them, let us know if they are completely removed.

Comment: This is a good workaround but it doesn't answer the question of whether it is necessary.

Comment: Agreed, but instead of saying that we don't know, by providing an option, they can use this "workaround" and find out if it does remove the voice memos. And they can also inform us, so we can be educated and help educate others on the matter.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson If you are confident that this works, why don't you try it first, and then post your procedure as your answer?

Comment: I don't have voice memos in my music app, they are in my voice memo app where they belong. Just back them up via dropbox (you can even make a free account) then once backed up, remove them from the music app. Or you can choose to opt out and wait for someone that has tried this before and see what their response was. It's likely that most people don't do what you have done.